# JPA redundant databases

Tags: java, database, jpa, backup

I'm developing a webshop using Java. I am using JPA to handle my data and store it in a database. Now I'm concerned with the scenario of losing any data. What is a best practice to prevent this?

Should I write changes to a local and a remote database using to EntityManagers? I'm using a VPS, would this result in a securityleak as I would need to transfer the data over the internet?

I don't think a backup to a SQL-file or some simular option would suffice, as I might lose a recently placed order this way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent data loss due to hardware or database failure, the most obvious solution is to use a database product that has replication or hot-standby capability built in.

Data that has been transferred to a remote location that you don't control would be a security concern, but the transfer itself should not be a concern.  It is simple to secure the network connection used to transfer the data.  Any decent database system will support SSL / TLS connections.

The problem with a simple backup system is that any updates made since the last completed backup may be lost.

Comment: +1 for a sane answer. Couple this with a durable journal to persist transactions between database backups and you have a pretty resilient system.

Comment: Hmm thanks, will consider it. Would mean that my remote destination needs an SSL-certificate.

Comment: *"Would mean that my remote destination needs an SSL-certificate."* - well yea, but that is pretty much mandatory for securing any communication over an untrusted network.